# why use husky with pre-commit if I can just use pre-commit

Tags: javascript, pre-commit-hook, husky

Ive used husky before however I noticed that I can just use pre-commit as is.

Since node now supports pre and post running of scripts wouldn't husky be kinda overkill?

Comment: How is node related to git in this situation?

Comment: in your package.json you can run example: `"prelint": "prettier --check ."` so inside your scripts in the package.json adding this will run the prettier before running the lint task

Comment: `husky` is used to run commands before `git` hooks, like `commit` or `push`. I don't see how `prelint` could be used here.